# Cannot run windbg on windows server 2008 R2 standard

Tags: windows, windbg, windows-server-2008-r2

I have latest windows server 2008 R2  standard on which multiple people have accounts .

I recently installed Windbg on it. However  I am unable to run the same as it gives the following error .

Kindly note that I am having all genuine OS which is completely up to date with the latest security updates .

```
    windbg.exe - Entry Point Not Found
    ---------------------------
    The procedure entry point RtlCopyContext could not be located 
in the dynamic link library ntdll.dll. 
    ---------------------------
    OK   
    ---------------------------
```

[image]

On doing a google  found many people suggesting running scanners and antivirus programs. I have done that but that didn't help .

My  Windbg version is

[image]

**ANSWER:**
The answer is in comments by @Hans Passant but putting it here so that anyone else can get benefited as well .

I had to install older version of windows sdk to get an older windbg which was specific to windows server 2008 r2  . My iso name was en_windows_software_development_kit_for_windows_7_and_windows_server_2008_r2_x64_dvd_400021.iso

Comment: Does running SFC (System File Checker) reveal anything? Which version of WinDbg?

Comment: SFC did not show any information . Since this is managed by my IT , my IT said they did not got anything .  Details are now shared in original quesitons . File version is 10.0.10586.212

Comment: You'll have to find an older version of windbg, one that doesn't require Windows 10.  Use SDK version 7.1 for example.

Comment: have you installed the Sp1 + all updates? I can run the Windbg version on Win7 Sp1 with all recent updates,

Answer (score 2):

The more recent versions(preview versions) of Debugging Tools for Windows require the most recent Universal CRT update. You should get this through Windows Update or https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48234